# Delayed mysql query and then bulk running

Tags: php, mysql, caching, widget

I have a widget which has several articles displayed. For each articles there are are about 2 selects and 1 insert/update.

The worst case scenario involves a widget displaying 300 articles and this involves 900 queries plus the other setup queries for the widget and this really slows the widget down. Now imagine that along with the widget being loaded by 5 users simultaneously sometimes.

I was thinking if I should collect all the queries for each widget and then write them in a file. Later have a cron job run periodically where those queries are executed every 30 seconds.

How much difference would this make to the performance. Also, does anyone else have a better system or idea.

What does websites like youtube, etc use for caching the views of the youtube videos.

I cannot optimize the widget any more. I want a solution for a delayed page counter lets say/

Comment: more info is needed(like some code), sounds like you need to optimise your query

Answer (score 0):

Using a cron job to do this kind of heavy work is not a bad idea : just have your cronjob generate the HTML output, and use that HTML from your PHP code, when displaying the page.

This way :

- The page will be fast to display : just one static HTML data/file to include/read
- There will never be more than 1 user (the cronjob) doing all the heavy querying.

But, seriously, 900 queries for a widget ? 3 queries for a single article ?

There is really something that should be improved, here !

Comment: I cant...There is only one select query to get the data for the article.

Comment: The rest is for the analytics purposes.

Comment: However I do use caching for the selects so it is like 300 select queries per second once every 15 seconds. But the inserts are 600 per widget load.

Comment: There might be a way to re-group your queries, doing a single query to get all 300 articles in a single query ? Like using joins, or a condition such as `where id in (...)` ? ;;; note that selects scale better than inserts : inserts mean locks on the database, so you can have a lot more concurrent selects than inserts.

Comment: The selects are not a problem and it is a joined query but it is like getting top 2 articles from each site. And then another query that I can't disclose due to security reasons. getting top 2 articles casues 150 sub queries and 1 main query.